# RecyclerView is displaying Null Value but No Error in the log

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to display list using recycler view but I am getting `null` value. I have three classes `Test`, `TestModel` and `TestListAdapter`. Below is my Json Output. I am getting an error in one place.

`val catObj = response.getJSONObject(i)`.

If I mention `i` as `int` then I am getting an error so, I need to enter `i.toString()` for string conversion. Even after converting the `i` to string, I am not getting the output and no error in the error log. I am using `Volley` and `Kotlin` in my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
Error:--Type Mismatch

 val catObj = response.getJSONObject(i)
```

Json Output:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"AAAA"},{"id":"3","name":"BBBB"}]
```

Test Class:

```
class Test : AppCompatActivity() {

var volleyRequest:RequestQueue?=null
var TestList: ArrayList<TestModel>?=null
var adapter:TestListAdapter?=null
var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager?=null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Test)


 var HelloLink="https://www.abc.app"
 TestList= ArrayList<TestModel>()
 volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    getTest(HelloLink)
}

fun getTest(url: String) {

    print("Url Value is:"+url)
    val catRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, Response.Listener {
        response: JSONObject ->
        try {
            for (i in 0..response.length() - 1) {
                val Test=TestModel()
                val catObj = response.getJSONObject(i)

                var name = catObj.getString("name")

                Test.name = name
                Log.d("Name Result==>>", name)
                TestList!!.add(Test)
                adapter = TestListAdapter(TestList!!, this)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                recyclerViewTest.layoutManager = layoutManager
                recyclerViewTest.adapter = adapter
            }

            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()


        }catch (e: JSONException) { e.printStackTrace()}

    },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                error: VolleyError? ->
                try {
                    Log.d("Error:", error.toString())

                }catch (e: JSONException){e.printStackTrace()}
            })
    volleyRequest!!.add(catRequest)
}
```

}

TestListAdapter Class

```
    class TestListAdapter(private val list:ArrayList<TestModel>,
                              private val context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<TestListAdapter.ViewHolder>()

    {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {

            val view 

=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_Test,p0,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        p0?.bindItem(list[p1])
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItem(Test:TestModel)
        {
            var name:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CatName)
            name.text=Test.name

        }
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
class TestModel
{
    var id:Int?=null
    var name:String?=null

}
```

Comment: I do not do kotlin but it would appear as if this part of the code `response: JSONObject ->` means that `response` should be a `JSONObject` but according to the JSON example in your question the JSON is actually a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned on my comment--I am not that familiar with the kotlin language, but the JSON example you posted:

> [{"id":"1","name":"AAAA"},{"id":"3","name":"BBBB"}]

is actually an `JSONArray` not a `JSONObject` so I think the code you should look like this:

```
fun getTest(url: String) {

    print("Url Value is:"+url)
    val catRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, Response.Listener {
        response: JSONArray ->
        try {
            for (i in 0..response.length() - 1) {
                val Test=TestModel()
                val catObj = response.getJSONObject(i)

                var name = catObj.getString("name")

                Test.name = name
                Log.d("Name Result==>>", name)
                TestList!!.add(Test)
                adapter = TestListAdapter(TestList!!, this)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                recyclerViewTest.layoutManager = layoutManager
                recyclerViewTest.adapter = adapter
            }

            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()


        }catch (e: JSONException) { e.printStackTrace()}

    },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                error: VolleyError? ->
                try {
                    Log.d("Error:", error.toString())

                }catch (e: JSONException){e.printStackTrace()}
            })
    volleyRequest!!.add(catRequest)
}
```

Notice that the `JsonArrayRequest` is in place of the `JsonObjectRequest` and the response is `JSONArray` instead of the `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks Barns, for your response. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Accepted it. I am not sure how to close this one.

Comment: I already did and let me know if it still shows pending for solution.

Comment: @JoshvaJo :: Thanks you! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue when you add data to your adapter,

Update your adapter as below

```
class TestListAdapter( private val context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<TestListAdapter.ViewHolder>()

    private val list = arrayListOf<TestModel> 

    public fun injectData(list : ArrayList<TestModel>){
    this.list.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged() 
} 

    {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {

            val view 

=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_Test,p0,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        p0?.bindItem(list[p1])
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItem(Test:TestModel)
        {
            var name:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CatName)
            name.text=Test.name

        }
    }
}
```

and in your `TestClass`:

```
            adapter = TestListAdapter(this)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recyclerViewTest.layoutManager = layoutManager
            recyclerViewTest.adapter = adapter

         try {
            for (i in 0..response.length() - 1) {
                val Test=TestModel()
                val catObj = response.getJSONObject(i)

                var name = catObj.getString("name")

                Test.name = name
                Log.d("Name Result==>>", name)
                TestList!!.add(Test)
            }

            adapter.injectData(TestList);


        }catch (e: JSONException) { e.printStackTrace()}
```

And the minor thing, please consider when using `!!`, you should check null before using

Example, Instead of

```
TestList!!.add(Test)
```

Try

```
TestList?.let {
  it.add(Test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gianh Tran for your response. After change into JsonArray Request Request the code worked fine.